# resizing responsive nav bar

Tags: jquery, css

So i made a responsive nav bar: At the normal view (1200px) it are inline-block elements shown side by side. When i shrink it to 767px it becomes a toggle button. So when click it it opens the navigation bar in block. When i click it again it closes. Now when i resize back to the full 1200px the navigation bar is gone.
I suppose that it has something to do with closing the menu when i'm at 767px and then making it reappear when i am back at 1200px but i can't figure it out

Here is my jquery code:

```
$('.js--nav-icon').click(function(){
    var nav = $('.js--main-nav');
    var icon = $('.js--nav-icon i');
    nav.slideToggle(200);
    if(icon.hasClass('ion-navicon-round')) {
        icon.addClass('ion-close-round');
        icon.removeClass('ion-navicon-round');
    } else {
        icon.addClass('ion-navicon-round');
        icon.removeClass('ion-close-round');
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: We will need more than just an inconclusive piece of jQuery code if you want us to help you. Make a fiddle or at least give us the CSS.

Comment: When you tweak CSS properties in Javascript / jQuery, you're setting them on the object, which will generally override CSS.  This is why we haven't used this paradigm in several years.  So, instead of using something like `slideToggle`, you should add classes and use CSS animation instead.   Can you mitigate it?  Sure.  Is it the right modern solution?  No, and jQuery adding things like `slideToggle` is very much an artifact of deprecated thinking.

Comment: So this is the link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ajc6amay/

at the end of the css i also included my queries when resizing. I hope it is enough info. thx